# Compute average provided by user using while and if

Tags: python, python-3.x

My program is supposed to take an inputs from the user and provide the average. If the number input is less than 0 it is supposed to end. My program is stuck in a loop of asking the user to enter a number instead of computing the average.

```
  a=-1
    s=0
    c=0
    I=input('Please enter a number')
    I=float(I)
    while I >= 0:
         s += I
         c +=1
         I=input('Please enter a number')
         I=float(I)
    if c>0:
       a= s/c
       print(a)
    else:
        print("No input, cannon compute the average")
```

Comment: You only asked for input once. You need to ask again inside the loop if you want to keep accepting input

Comment: @jeffcarey I added in an input within the loop and also a print(a) under a=s/c. However now, i'm stuck in a loop of "please enter a number"

Comment: Mike's answer below does exactly what your assignment requires. Maybe you should read it again!

Comment: @ThierryLathuille It just keeps asking to enter a number, it never does the a=s/c

Comment: In your own words: If the number input is less than 0 it is supposed to end. And if you want to print the average after each number you enter, then you have to do it in the loop.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille haha you are right that is what I said. I meant if its less than 0 it ends. But its still supposed to compute the average with the positive numbers

Comment: @ThierryLathuille nevermind im stupid. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this

```
a=-1
s=0
c=0
I=input('Please enter a number')
I=float(I)
while I >= 0:
     s += I
     c +=1
     I=input('Please enter a number')
     I=float(I)
if c>0:
   a= s/c
   print(a)
else:
    print("No input, cannon compute the average")
```

Comment: If I do that, its in a never ending loop and never computes the average

Answer (score 0):

```
theSum = 0
counter = 0
numberEntered = float(input('Please enter a number: '))
while(numberEntered >= 0):
    theSum += numberEntered
    counter += 1
    numberEntered = float(input('Please enter a number: '))
if counter > 0:
    print(theSum/counter)
else:
    print("No input, cannot compute the average.")
```